# Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ if $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$, with $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}h(x)=g(a)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove that if $f$, $g$ and $h$ are three functions defined in a neighbourhood $(a-r,a+r)$ of $a$, such that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= \lim_{x\to a} h(x)=g(a)$ and for all $x \in (a-r,a+r)$ we have $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ then $g$ is continuous at $a$.

I just want to confirm if my solution is correct/the right idea:

Since we know $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= \lim_{x\to a} h(x)=g(a)$ then by the squeeze theorem $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=g(a)$ and by a theorem in class, since $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=g(a)$, $g(x)$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 2):

The continuity of $g(x)$ at $x=a$ indeed follows from the squeeze theorem, so your proof is correct. I would like to add that $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=g(a)\text{ implies }g(x)\text{ is continous at }a$$ not because of a **theorem**, but because it is the **definition** of continuity at $a$.